# Bootstrap Navbar Expanding on Hover

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I just updated the navbar of a project I'm working on to a Bootstrap navbar. I have modified the Bootstrap a tiny bit. The problem seemed to happen when I added `width: 80%;` and `margin-left: 20%;` to make the navbar span the whole page and have **on the very left** the "brand". You can see the problem here: http://output.jsbin.com/mumuna. Source code: https://github.com/CSGOFlair/dev

Comment: Remove margin from li a:hover

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, LionWaffles.
Here we would like to see a minimal test case of whatever is not working and not Github and JSBin links.

Comment: I put the JSBin link so people can see the issue reproduced and the code that caused it to fail. I don't really get what you're asking me. Do you want the links removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are adding margin to anchor tag on hover.

So, change:

```
li a:hover {
    background-color: #00a8a8;
    margin: 25px 10px;
}
```

on line 47 in https://github.com/CSGOFlair/dev/blob/gh-pages/css/stylesheet.css to

```
li a:hover {
    background-color: #00a8a8;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Which file would that be? We have multiple CSS files :(

Comment: Check the updated answer, You can find the code on this page at line 47 https://github.com/CSGOFlair/dev/blob/gh-pages/css/stylesheet.css

Comment: You fixed it, thank you so much for the descriptive answer!